# How to start text view from the right in a button android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I have a button with an icon and a text inside of it. When I set the button's width to `match_parent`, the text inside the button gets placed in the middle. I want the text to start from the right side of the button and not in the middle. How can I achieve this?

```
<Button
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/select_flight_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/button_material_light"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_select_flight"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/global_button_height"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/global_button_height"
    android:text="@string/choose_flight"
    android:textColor="@drawable/custom_text_color_for_buttons"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: android:gravity="right" with parent as LinearLayout will help

Comment: `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"`

Comment: it's not right , It's centered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Picture and requirement doesn't match**
It is right and centerVertical and starting from right

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Chooose Flight "
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Using android:gravity="center_vertical" worked for me.

Comment: So check my answer as right . Check the green icon plz